# how do i create the remember me on login with firebase me on the routes.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

this is an ionic app with firebase google authentication in it. i wanna know the correct way of doing this coz my login logic works but the routing crashes the app. unfortunately there are no errors on console the app just goes blank.

```js
angular.module('app.routes', ['app.controllers','firebase'])


.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
{
  $stateProvider

      .state('tabsController.allTasks', {
    url: '/alltasks',
    views: {
      'tab1': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/allTasks.html',
        controller: 'allTasksCtrl',
        resolve : {

        }

      }
    }
  })

  .state('tabsController', {
    url: '/page1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabsController.html',
    abstract:true
  })

  .state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
    controller: 'signupCtrl'
  })

  .state('onboarding', {
  url: '/onboarding',
  templateUrl: 'templates/onboarding.html',
  controller: 'onBoardingCtrl'
})

  .state('logOut', {
    url: '/logout',
    templateUrl: 'templates/logOut.html',
    controller: 'logOutCtrl'
  })

  .state('taskdetail', {
    url: '/taskdetail',
    templateUrl: 'templates/taskdetail.html',
    controller: 'allTasksCtrl'
  })



    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user)
    {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('tabsController.allTasks')
    }
    else
    {
          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login')
    }
});
```

Comment: Please check this out https://github.com/firebase/angularfire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that firebase block of code in your .config and instead insert this in a .run block.

```
.run(function($state) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
  var authData = ref.getAuth();

  if (authData) {
    $state.go('tabsController.allTasks');
  } else {
    $state.go('login');
  }
})
```

Comment: the problem is that when i log() the authData i get a null. i'd login refresh and try again im still getting a null.

Comment: this works only on browser but not on android device

Comment: Try 1. adding cordova-plugin-whitelist and 2. whitelisting the Firebase domain https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com in config.xml so that Android can communicate with that url https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/whitelist/